# Error Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is my code and i am getting an error ..Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList. when the page loads it select "ALL" in DDLModality but when i change DDLModality.selectedvalue to any "value" then no error but again when i change to "ALL "getting the error.

onchange of DDLMODALITY submit the form
                form1.target = "";
            form1.action = "";
                form1.submit();

```
 ' USED TO ADD REFERRING PHYSICIAN IN THE DROPDOWN DYNAMICALLY 
    If CInt(Session("CenterID")) = 0 Then
        sql = "Select Ref_Phy_ID,Name from Ref_Phy_Master WHERE Ref_Phy_ID in(Select distinct Ref_Phy_ID from Patient_Details where Ref_Phy_ID <> '')"
    Else
        sql = "Select Ref_Phy_ID,Name from Ref_Phy_Master WHERE Ref_Phy_ID in(Select distinct Ref_Phy_ID from Patient_Details where Ref_Phy_ID <> '') And Center_ID = " & Session("CenterID")
    End If
    objDS = objFun.RunQuery(sql)
    ' USED TO REFRESH THE PAGE WHIN IT IS POSTED BACK 
    ' USED TO DISPLAY DEFAULT FIRST ITEM IN THE DROPDOWN 
    Dim Li1 As New ListItem()
    Li1.Text = "ALL"
    Li1.Value = ""
    cboRefPhy.Items.Add(Li1)
    ' USED TO COUNT THE STUDIES IN THE DROPDOWN 
    If (objDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0) Then
        ' USED TO CIRCULATE LOOP UPTO THE RECORD COUNT
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To objDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            ' USED TO CREATE NEW ITEM IN THE DROPDOWN 
            Dim Li As New ListItem
            Li.Text = objDS.Tables(0).Rows(i)("Name").ToString()
            Li.Value = objDS.Tables(0).Rows(i)("Ref_Phy_ID").ToString()
            'USED TO ADD ITEMS IN THE DROPDOWN 
            cboRefPhy.Items.Add(Li)
        Next
    End If
    'USED TO SAVE THE CHANGES IN DATASET  
    objDS.AcceptChanges()
    ' USED TO CLOSE THE DATABASE CONNECTION 
    objDS.Dispose()
    cboRefPhy.ClearSelection()
    cboRefPhy.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(Request.Form("cboRefPhy"))

    'USED TO ADD MODALITY IN THE DROPDOWN DYNAMICALLY
    If CInt(Session("CenterID")) = 0 Then
        sqlStudy = "Select Modality_ID,Modality from Hospital_Modality_Master WHERE Modality_ID in(Select distinct Study_ID from Patient_Details where Study_ID <> '')"
    Else
        sqlStudy = "Select Modality_ID,Modality from Hospital_Modality_Master WHERE Modality_ID in(Select distinct Study_ID from Patient_Details where Study_ID <> '') And Center_ID = " & Session("CenterID")
    End If
    'Dim objDS As New DataSet()
    objDS = objFun.RunQuery(sqlStudy)
    ' USED TO REFRESH THE PAGE WHIN IT IS POSTED BACK 
    ' USED TO DISPLAY DEFAULT FIRST ITEM IN THE DROPDOWN 
    'Dim Li1 As New ListItem()
    Li1.Text = "ALL"
    Li1.Value = ""
    ' Dim all As String
    ' all = "All"
    'Ddl_Modality.Items.Add(all)
    DDLModality.Items.Add(Li1)
    ' USED TO COUNT THE STUDIES IN THE DROPDOWN 
    If (objDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0) Then
        ' USED TO CIRCULATE LOOP UPTO THE RECORD COUNT
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To objDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            ' USED TO CREATE NEW ITEM IN THE DROPDOWN 
            Dim Li As New ListItem
            Li.Text = objDS.Tables(0).Rows(i)("Modality").ToString()
            Li.Value = objDS.Tables(0).Rows(i)("Modality_ID").ToString()
            'USED TO ADD ITEMS IN THE DROPDOWN 
            DDLModality.Items.Add(Li)
        Next
    End If
    'USED TO SAVE THE CHANGES IN DATASET  
    objDS.AcceptChanges()
    ' USED TO CLOSE THE DATABASE CONNECTION 
    objDS.Dispose()
    DDLModality.ClearSelection()
    DDLModality.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(Request.Form("DDLModality"))


    ' USED TO ADD STUDY IN THE DROPDOWN DYNAMICALLY 
    If CInt(Session("CenterID")) = 0 Then
        sqlStudy = "Select Study_ID,Study_Desc from Study_Master WHERE Study_ID in(Select distinct Study_ID from Patient_Details where Study_ID <> '')"
    Else
        sqlStudy = "Select Study_ID,Study_Desc from Study_Master WHERE Study_ID in(Select distinct Study_ID from Patient_Details where Study_ID <> '') And Center_ID = " & Session("CenterID")
    End If

    If (DDLModality.SelectedItem.Text <> "ALL") Then
        sqlStudy = sqlStudy & " AND Modality = '" & DDLModality.SelectedItem.Text & "'"

    End If
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know VB, but in C#, you could set DDLModality.SelectedValue = -1 before you say DDLModality.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(Request.Form("DDLModality")).  This will "de-select" any previous selection, so that when you DO select something, there isn't already a value selected.

Comment: As you code stands you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please please please use parameterized queries. See http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=parameterized+queries+c%23+sql+injection&oq=parameterized+queries+c%23+sql+injection&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=2628l30355l0l30542l28l20l1l6l6l0l156l1543l2.12l22l0&gs_l=hp.3...2628l30355l0l30542l28l20l1l6l6l0l156l1543l2j12l22l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=18235671e0456e0f&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1600&bih=799

Comment: why do you need DDLModality.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(Request.Form("DDLModality"))

Comment: i am getting the same error after seting DDLModality.SelectedValue = -1

Comment: Can you please post the rendered markup for the dropdown?

Comment: function JSFuntionName() {var DropdownList = document.getElementById('<%=DDLModality.ClientID %>');
         var SelectedIndex = DropdownList.selectedIndex;
         var SelectedValue = DropdownList.value;
         var SelectedText = DropdownList.options[DropdownList.selectedIndex].text;
         form1.target = "";
         form1.action = "";
            form1.submit();
     }<asp:DropDownList width="55%" ID="DDLModality" runat="server" class="ttsearch"  onchange="JavaScript:JSFuntionName();">                           </asp:DropDownList>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim Li2 As New ListItem()
      Li2.Text = "ALL"
      Li2.Value = ""  
      DDLModality.Items.Add(Li2)
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
DDLModality.ClearSelection()
```

before setting `DDLModality.SelectedValue`

Comment: Do you have repeating items in the Dropdownlist?

Comment: No//when the page loads it select "ALL" in DDLModality but when i change DDLModality.selectedvalue to any "value" then no error but again when i change to "ALL "getting the error..

Comment: Dim Li2 As New ListItem()
    Li2.Text = "ALL"
    Li2.Value = ""    
    DDLModality.Items.Add(Li2)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. If you add one defined ListItem (in this case Li1) to two or more dropdownlists, this error will occur while assigning selectedvalue to any dropdownlist.

*Simple solution is define separate ListItems for separate dropdownlists like Li1, Li2, Li3, etc.*

Don't understand the logic behind, but it works!